# Can't figure out geometric sequence homework

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone help me figure out how to do these equations I've tried looking online but nothing is helping I have a terrible and she can't explain how to do these at all. 
78
5) Σ4k−1 6) Σ(−6)i−1
k=1 i=1
99
7) Σ2i−1 8) Σ−2m−1
i=1 m=1
89
9) Σ2⋅(−2)n−1 10) Σ4⋅3n−1
n=1 n=1
10 9
11) Σ4⋅(−3)n−1 12) Σ(−2)n−1
n=1 n=1

Comment: You're going to have to do some editing for us to be able to read these.  Take a look here for a quick reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

In general, the sum of a geometric series is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=a(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r})$$  a represents the first term in the sequence.  r represents the common ratio.  However, it appears that your problems are not geometric series.  Rather it appears that they are arithmetic series.  For the sum of an arithmetic series use: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$$So for example, for (6) we take $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}a_{99}=\frac{99}{2}(3+a_{99})$$To find $a_{99}$ we use the formula $a_{n}=a_1+(n-1)d$ which gives $a_{99}=3+(99-1)(4)$ which simplifies to 395.

So, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}a_{99}=\frac{99}{2}(3+395)$$ which equals 19701.